# Get authenticated username as spring in Spring Flux application

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux

Currently I am new to kotlin and spring flux.

Im trying to get the logged in user as a string without needing to return a Mono object immediately.

currently I have a handler that is mapping a request to a DTO object. like the following

```
fun redeemLeave(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> =
    req.bodyToMono<RedeemLeaveDTO>().map { issuance ->
        val errors = validator.validate(issuance)
        if (errors.isNotEmpty()) {
            issuance.fieldErrors = errors.map {
                FieldErrorDTO(it.propertyPath.toString(), it.message)
            }
        }
        issuance
    }.flatMap {
        when (it.fieldErrors) {
            null -> employeeComposer.redeemLeave(it)
            else -> ServerResponse.unprocessableEntity().body(Mono.just(it))
        }
    }
```

I have another endpoint where I can get the username, but there's no dto mapping so it works well.

```
fun requestBalance(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> =
    req.principal()
        .map(Principal::getName).flatMap { username ->
            employeeComposer.requestBalance(username)
        }
```

How do I get the username from the principal() call? is there a better way? I would like to be able to get the username for the first method as well as have a dto transformation.

Comment: you can get the body, and the principal and then `zip` them together

Comment: would you have an example?

Comment: Actually I would need the username as a string to be passed to the service in the first call.